# Bessel function relation

Tags: bessel-functions

I need to show that
$$
\sin(ar\sin\zeta)\cos\zeta+ \sin(ar\cos\zeta)\sin\zeta=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\cfrac{8(2m+1)}{ar}J_{2(2m+1)}(ar)\sin[2(2m+1)\zeta]
$$

I think I have to use the relationships
$$
\sin(ar\sin\zeta)=2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}J_{2n+1}(ar)\sin[(2n+1)\zeta]\\
\sin(ar\cos\zeta)=2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^nJ_{2n+1}(ar)\cos[(2n+1)\zeta]
$$

Substituting these relationships in the left side of the first equality, I see that I come with the two products $\sin[(2n+1)\zeta]\cos\zeta$ and $\cos[(2n+1)\zeta]\sin\zeta$ which can be reduced to $\sin[(2n+2)\zeta]+\sin(2n\zeta)$. Hence I can consider the sum

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}[J_{2n+1}(ar)+(-1)^nJ_{2n+1}(ar)]
$$
which is zero for odd $n$. So i can put $n=2m$ and get
$$
2\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}[J_{4m+1}(ar)]
$$
but now I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong in the proposed attempt. As mentioned in the OP, using the given identities, we obtain
\begin{align}
 S&=\sin(ar\sin\zeta)\cos\zeta+ \sin(ar\cos\zeta)\sin\zeta\\
 &=2\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}J_{2n+1}(ar)\left\lbrace\sin[(2n+1)\zeta]\cos\zeta+(-1)^n\cos[(2n+1)\zeta]\sin\zeta\right\rbrace
 \end{align}
Decomposing the summation using the parity of the index $n$ gives
\begin{align}
 S&=2\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}J_{4p+1}(ar)\sin[(4p+2)\zeta]+2\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}J_{4p+3}(ar)\sin[(4p+2)\zeta]\\
 &=2\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\sin[(4p+2)\zeta]\left[J_{4p+1}(ar)+J_{4p+3}(ar)\right]
\end{align}
Now, using the [recurrence relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.6.E1)
\begin{equation}
  J_{\nu-1}\left(z\right)+J_{\nu+1}\left(z\right)=(2\nu/z)J_{\nu}\left(z\right)
 \end{equation}
with $\nu=4p+2$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
  S=\frac{8}{ar}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}(2p+1)\sin[(4p+2)\zeta]J_{4p+2}(ar)
 \end{equation}

Comment: You're completely right, I went wrong with the trigonometric relationships. Now I got it.